# Modifying PATH variable via Ansible

Tags: ansible

Below is the bash profile of the root user in my system.

```
[root@newvm-2 ~]# cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

I want to write a ansible code that will add the below path at the end of PATH in the bash_profile of root user:

/usr/edb/efm
eg: the new PATH will look like

`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/edb/efm`

Comment: Any help on this..

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what error is it producing for you? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- lineinfile:
    regexp: '^(PATH=.*)$'
    backrefs: yes
    line: '\1:/user/edb/efm'
    path: '/root/.bashrc'
```

lineinfile manipulates individual lines in files.
`regexp: '^(PATH=.*)$'` says: Find the last line beginning with `PATH=` and remember the line. This also specifies which line will be changed.
`backrefs: yes` means that I can use that remembered line in the line I set.
`line: '\1:/user/edb/efm'` means take the first group the regex matched (the entire line in the `()` ) and write `:/user/edb/efm` behind it.
`path: '/root/.bashrc'` just specifies which file is manipulated, I guessed here, you probably know the right one.

This is just a single task, if you want a whole play for this just prepend

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
```

and indent everything once

Comment: If this worked, consider accepting my answer